# Array keeps being filled

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I've got an Array of items on which I'd like to iterate and add new values or update old ones.

I've written this code, but it keeps adding values while it shouldn't and I really can't figure out why. Can someone help me with this? Here's the relevant code of the function (VueJS2)

```
processResponse: function(backendCall, arrayToManage) {
    backendCall().then(responseData => {
        responseData.forEach(response => {
            let index = arrayToManage.findIndex(function(item) {
                item.name === response.name;
            });
            (index === -1) ? arrayToManage.push(response) : arrayToManage[index] = response;
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks for you help!

N.B.: I forgot to mention that this call is surrounded by a setInterval call which is ran every second

Comment: Yo need to return this `item.name === response.name;`, just add `return` before this

Comment: Thanks mate, still confused about those return statements.